# how to reset form with angular

Tags: angularjs, reset

this is my code:

```
function CustomersController ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/ci_angular/api/customers/').success(function(customers){
        $scope.customers = customers;
    });

    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
        var customer = {
            customerName: $scope.customerNameText,
            email: $scope.emailText,
            address: $scope.addressText,
            city: $scope.cityText,
            state: $scope.stateText,
            postalCode: $scope.postalCodeText,
            country: $scope.countryText,
        };

        $scope.customers.push(customer);

        // update 1

        $http.post('/ci_angular/api/customers/customer', customer);

        $scope.emptyCustomers= {};

        $scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.customers = angular.copy($scope.emptyCustomers);
        };

        // update 2

        $http.post('/ci_angular/api/customers/customer', customer)
            .success(function() {           
                 $scope.emptyCustomers= {};

                 $scope.customerForm.$setPristine();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

After the post success, I want to reset all the form field, but its not working,
my form name is customerForm, is there something I missed? thanks in advance

Comment: What version of angular?

Comment: Im using angular 1.2.5 sir

Comment: Do you want to reset the $dirty flags on your form fields for validation purposes? or do you want to clear the fields? They are two different things.

Comment: So the form to add a customer and the table of customer list is in 1 page, I want to clear the form field after submitting the new customer, which one it is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to reset your form fields $dirty flags after a successful ajax call, then you should call setPristine() from inside of your success handler:

```
    $http.post('/ci_angular/api/customers/customer', customer)
        .success(function() {           
             $scope.customerForm.$setPristine();
        });
```

If you want to clear your form fields, then you should initialize a model inside your controller, so that you can bind them to the view, and clear them out later:

Controller:

```
function CustomersController ($scope, $http) {
    // initialize an empty customer. 
    $scope.customer = {};
    // its good practice to initialize your customers array too
    $scope.customers = [];

    $http.get('/ci_angular/api/customers/').success(function(customers){
        $scope.customers = customers;
    });

    $scope.addCustomer = function(customer){

        $http.post('/ci_angular/api/customers/customer', customer).success(function() {
            // push the customers to the array only when its successful
            $scope.customers.push(customer);

            // clearing the customer form is easy now, just set it to an empty object
            $scope.customer = {};
        });

    }
}

var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('CustomersController', CustomersController);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CustomersController">
     <form name="customerForm">
            customerName:<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="customer.name" /><br />
            email: <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="customer.email" /><br />
            address: <input type="text" name="address" ng-model="customer.address" /><br />
            city: <input type="text" name="city" ng-model="customer.city" /><br />
            state: <input type="text" name="state" ng-model="customer.state" /><br />
            postalCode: <input type="text" name="postalcode" ng-model="customer.postalCode" /><br />
            country: <input type="text" name="country" ng-model="customer.country" /><br />

        <button ng-click="addCustomer(customer)">Add Customer</button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
      var customer = {
        customerName: '',
        email: '',
        address: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        postalCode: '',
        country: '',
      };
```

Place this code in your success function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a reset button on html and have reset function in $scope as below :

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
```

**JS to add inside controller**

```
$scope.emptyCustomers= {};

$scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.customers = angular.copy($scope.emptyCustomers);
};
```

Check Angularjs docs simple form for similar example : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Hope this helps !

Comment: Not working sir, is it possible to reset the form without using ng-click? check out my updated question